# Angularjs: How to avoid filtering if I enter value other than [1,2,3,4]?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to avoid filtering when I put other number in the text-box like 0 or 5 etc.

```
<div ng-app="">
<input type="text" ng-model="search">

<div ng-repeat='val in [1,2, 3, 4] | filter:search'>
  {{val}}
</div>
```

I am new to angular. How to do that?

I included [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pNWC/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V31's answer is the way you want to go.  Unless your question is just a generalized version of what you are trying to do.

[fiddle showing filter by function](http://jsfiddle.net/4pNWC/11/)

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.col = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    $scope.go = function(search) {
        if (!search) return null;
        var val = parseInt(search);
        return $scope.col.indexOf(val) > -1 ? val : null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Woww.. This is what I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use if ng-pattern in the textbox so it will not trigger the filter

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pNWC/1/)

Code Snippet:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[1-4]$/" ng-model="search">
```

Comment: @krishna: I thought a one line change would have been better rather than going for js filter function in this case